# What are some machine learning problems that can be attacked with continuous multiobjective optimization?

Tags: deep-learning, svm, logistic-regression, optimization, gradient-descent

I am working on continuous vector optimization, and hence continuous multiobjective optimization is a particular case. I am interested in finding applications in machine learning for this problems. Is there any algorithm/application on which you could use Pareto/weak Pareto optimal points as the optimal parameters? I was wondering whether there exists something like a multiobjective version of logistic regression or least squares. Any pointer to the literature will also be very helpful.